# Java handling billions bytes

Tags: java, bigdata

I'm creating a **compression** algorithm in **Java**;
to use my algorithm I require a lot of **information about the structure** of the target file.

After collecting the data, I need to **reread the file.**  ***<- But I don't want to.***

While rereading the file, I make it **a good target for compression** by **'converting'** the data of the file to a rather peculiar format. Then I compress it.

The **problems** now are:

1. I don't want to open a new FileInputStream for rereading the file.
2. I don't want to save the converted file which is usually 150% the size of the target file to the disk.

Are there any ways to **'reset'** a FileInputStream for **moving to the start of the file,** and how would I store the **huge amount 'converted' data** efficiently without writing to the disk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use one or more RandomAccessFiles.  You can memory map them to ByteBuffer() which doesn't consume heap (actually they use about 128 bytes) or direct memory but can be accessed randomly.

Your temporary data can be storing in a direct ByteBuffer(s) or more memory mapped files.  Since you have random access to the original data, you may not need to duplicate as much data in memory as you think.

This way you can access the whole data with just a few KB of heap.

Answer (score 0):

There's the [`reset`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#reset%28%29) method, but you need to wrap the `FileInputStream` in a `BufferedInputStream`.

Comment: `reset()` requires that the buffer all the data between when you call mark() and reset().

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yeah, I realized that after posting--will delete.

Comment: I think its a good solution, just not going to work so well here.

Answer (score 0):

You could use RandomAccessFile, or java.nio ByteBuffer is what you are looking for. (I do not know.)

Resources might be saved by pipes/streams: immediately writing to a compressed stream.

To answer your questions on **reset**: not possible; the base class InputStream has provisions for mark and reset-to-mark, but FileInputStream was made optimal for several operating systems and does purely sequential input. Closing and opening is best.

Comment: Wrapping the file input with a buffered input is the way around that. Not appropriate in this case, however.