# How to handle big data with Java framework?

Tags: java, bigdata

I'm fairly new to data science, and now just starting to develop a system that required me to analyze large data (e.g. 5 - 6 million records in each DBs).

In a bigger picture: I have multiple DBs containing various kind of data which need to be integrated. After integrating the data, I also need to perform some data analysis. And lastly, I need to visualize the data to many clients.

Overall,I want to know what is the current technology/trend for handling big data (i.e with java framework)

Comment: So you're basically asking "How to do big data"?. That is a whole research field, and in my opinion, way too broad for SO.

Comment: any tries yet???? tip: search for common and usual queries, optimize them, think how to group this data to create indexes (integrating data for fast reading) make your analysis and show results.....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7984740/java-handling-billions-bytes?rq=1

Comment: @JordiCastilla Has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: I just want to know the bigger picture, what is the current technology/trend for handling big data (i.e with java framework)

Comment: Also, how much is "5 - 6 million data"? Is it 5 - 6 million records in a database? 5 - 6 million mega-/gigabytes?

Comment: @lexicore your opinion, not mine......  be my guest and show us correct way please....

Comment: gotta edit question

Comment: @JordiCastilla The correct way is to close this question as "too broad".

Comment: @ChocoretoAgastya Please check the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for what's on topic. You are asking a very broad question - and also ask for a tool/technology recommendation or review. Both are not appropriate for SO.

Comment: @lexicore thats totally false... the correct way is to guide the user to correct question and provide missing information

Comment: @lexicore what you just did......

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is: Depends of your non-functional requirements. Your use cases will be critical in deciding which technology to use.
Let me share one of my experience, in order to clarify what I mean:

In 2012 I needed to deal with ~2 million non-structured records per month, and perform algorithms of entropy (information theory) and similarity for ~600 requests per minute.
Our scenario were composed by:

- Records non-structured, but already in JSON format.
- The algorithms for entropy and similarity were based in all content of the DB vs records to be matched (Take a look in [Shannon entropy formula][1], and you will understand the complexity I'm talking about)
- more them 100 different web applications as clients of this solution.

Given those requirements (and many others), and after performing PoCs with [Casandra][2], [Hadoop][3], [Voldmort][4], [neo4j][5], and also tests of stress, resiliency, scalability, and robustness, we arrived in the best solution for that moment (2012):

- Java EE 7 (with the new Garbage-First (G1) collector activated)

  - JBoss AS 7 ([wildfly][6]) + [Infinispan][7] for the MapReduce race condition, among other clusters' control, and distributed cache needs.
- Servlet 3.0 (because it's Non-blocking I/O)
- [Nginx][8] (In that time was beta, but different of httpd2, it was already multiple connections in a non-blocking fashion)
- [mongoDB][9] (due our raw content already being in JSON document style)
- [Apache Mahout][10] for all algorithms implementation, including the MapReduce strategy
- among other stuffs.

So, all depends on your requirements. There's no silver bullet. Each situation demands an architectural analysis.

I remember Nasa in that time was processing ~1TB per hour in AWS with Hadoop, due the [Mars project with the Curiosity][11].

In your case, I would recommend paying attention in your requirements, maybe a Java framework it's not what you need (or not just what you need):

- If you are going just to implement algorithms for data analysis, statisticians and data miners (for example), probably [R programming language][12] is gonna be the best choice.
- If you need a really fast I/O (aircraft stuff for example): any native compiled language like [Go Lang][13], [C++][14], etc.
- But if actually you're going to create a web applications that actually will be just a client or feed the big data solution, I'd recommend something more soft and scalable like [nodeJS][15] or even a just in time compiled technology like those one based in JVM ([Scala][16], [Jython][17], Java) in [dockerized][18] [microservices][19]...

Good luck! (Sorry, the Stack Overflow didn't allow me to add the references link yet - But all I have talked about here, can easily been googled).